# Does shampoo containing pro-B5 affect the appearance of hair?

Tags: hair, vitamins, cosmetics

Many shampoos contain vitamins.

[Elvive Vitamax shampoo](http://www.co-operativepharmacy.co.uk/Elvive-Shampoo-Vitamax-250ml/id-3083821) for example, is [variously promised](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Elvive-Shampoo-Multi-Vitamins-250ml/dp/B001B23882%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAILSHYYTFIVPWUY6Q%26tag%3Dduc08-21%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB001B23882) to contain "Vitamin pro-B5" which

> makes hair full of vitality.

Is this additive useful?

Comment: I wonder what "full of vitality" means.

Comment: What is "Vitamin pro-B5", other than an ingredient? You need only carry out a set of double-blind tests: create some test bottles containing (a) Shampoo with "Vitamin pro-B5" (b) Shampoo without "Vitamin pro-B5", label them A or B, and give them to people to assess, without telling them what each contains. Ask people on a scale of 1 to 10, how much "vitality" they think there hair had before and after shampooing.

Comment: I always suggest to people believing in this kind of things to do a half-face or half-hair test. Use the product on half the face or half the hair and a similar product without the additive on the other half and compare. Never have anyone returned with evidence. I take this as marketing BS.